# Reuse connection in SAS proc sql

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sas

I've added remote library in such a way:

```
libname R rengine=db2 server=SYS1;
```

But i cannot use it inside `proc sql`:

```
25   proc sql;
26   connect using R;
ERROR: SERVER= option, required for connection, not found.
27   quit;
```

I don't want to connect every time again, because i need to make a lot of calls of stored procedures.

Local SAS9.4, remote SAS9.1.3

Comment: Can you make such a connection using a the CONNECT statement without the USING clause?  Is the information you need to complete the CONNECT statement available in the metadata in the SASHELP.VLIBNAM view?

Comment: What commands are you trying to submit that you cannot do just referencing libname R?  Could you just use an RSUBMIT block to submit the commands to the SAS server SYS1 instead?

Comment: @Tom, Well, if i double click connected library in explorer it says `<username> does not have the privilege to perform operation select on object sysibm.systables`. I can only call some stored procs via `proc sql`. I used to use `rsubmit`, today have found  an alternative: http://pastebin.com/7bW6Mrk5 But it would be cool to get data w/o connecting EVERY time again. I thought `using` could be used for that.

Comment: Sometimes i need to make thousands of stored proc calls. Connecting makes things much slower. The only possibility i see is to make several calls inside one `proc sql`.

Comment: Here's `vlibname` https://pp.vk.me/c630628/v630628561/2e68d/_AMbgSwmgs0.jpg (i used `sys1` server in examples for simplicity)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest just saving the information needed to create the libref in macro variables and then reuse them in defining the connection.

```
%let rengine=db2;
%let server=sys1;
libname R rengine=&rengine server=&server;
proc sql ;
  connect to remote(server=&server dbms=&rengine);
```

Or you could create the macro variables from the metadata saved in SASHELP.VLIBNAM (or DICTIONARY.LIBNAMES from within PROC SQL.).

```
proc sql ;
  select sysvalue into :server trimmed
    from dictionary.libnames
    where libname='R' and sysname='Accessed through server'
  ;
  select sysvalue into :rengine trimmed
    from dictionary.libnames
    where libname='R' and sysname="Server's engine"
  ;
  connect to remote(server=&server dbms=&rengine);
```

Comment: The main point is to improve performance when i have *many* `proc sql`. Are there any possibilities? Maybe it's better to use not so many `proc sql`s by grouping my calls?

Comment: You only need to start PROC SQL or CONNECT statement again if you close the current one.  Nothing should be stopping you from submitting many EXECUTE() statements in the same PROC SQL session.